# Fitting Maxwell-Boltzman distribution in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Is it possible to make a fit to Maxwell-Boltzmann like data in matplotlib or similar module in python?

Comment: Likely a `scipy` feature, not matplotlib.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

scipy.stats has support for the [maxwell distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html#scipy.stats.maxwell).

---

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

maxwell = stats.maxwell
data = maxwell.rvs(loc=0, scale=5, size=10000)

params = maxwell.fit(data, floc=0)
print(params)
# (0, 4.9808603062591041)

plt.hist(data, bins=20, normed=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)
plt.plot(x, maxwell.pdf(x, *params), lw=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The first parameter is the location or shift away from zero.
The second parameter is the scaling parameter, denoted by `a` on [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution).

To generate random variates (random data) with this distribution, use its `rvs` method:

```
newdata = maxwell.rvs(*params, size=100)
```

Comment: It looks like you would normally only use `loc=0` with the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, so you should probably use the option `floc=0` when you fit the data; that is, use `params = maxwell.fit(data, floc=0)`.  Without that, the `fit` method treats the location as one more free parameter to be included in the fit.